# Is there a way I can convert a FileInputStream to an Object without using ObjectInputStream?

Tags: java, binaryfiles

I was wondering if it was possible to get an object from a FileInputStream without using ObjectInputStream.

Why am I doing this? I've been working on a project recently, it reads .DAT files from a game and converts them to .OBJ - There is a catch to these .DAT files however: Their stream header is ALWAYS 0xFACEAF0E. Is there a way I can get around the restriction ObjectInputStream has on stream headers and get an Object from one of these files?

Here is the code I need help with.

```
package xan_code;

/*
 * Purpose: Determine file extension and run it through the code to move it to an OBJ.
 */

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import main.BeginConversion; //Import the conversion code. Returns a string based on the file
import xan_code.dathandler.ReadBinary; //Get the .DAT reading functions

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class HandleFiles extends Main { //Extend main to get the log from the opener UI.
    static BeginConversion converter = new BeginConversion(); //Get the converter for XML files since this will also read XMLs derived from the .DAT
    static String DatText = ""; //The "text" to return for the .DAT (To pack into the decoded file)
    static Object _object; //THIS IS THE VARIABLE OF THE OBJECT I NEED IN ORDER TO CONVERT THE .DAT TO A MODEL
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public static String convert(File file, boolean isXML, FileInputStream FIS) { //Convert. Passes in the .DAT or .XML file, a boolean to whether or not its extension is .XML, and the FileInputStream from file
        if (isXML) { //If it's an XML
            String xml = ""; //This is the text to store the XML as a string
            String obj = ""; //This is the text to store the WaveFront OBJ (Model format) as a string
            try {
                xml = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\Z").next(); //use the scanner to get the string of the XML
                obj = converter.BeginConvert(xml); //Pass the XML into the java files required to read from the XML and convert it to an OBJ. They return the text from an OBJ file.
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //Exceptions are handled before, though to be safe...
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return obj; //Return that text to Main so I can create the file.
        } else { //We have a .DAT
            try {
                //HELP REQUIRED HERE. NEED TO GET _object FROM THE FILE WITHOUT USING ObjectInputStream
                DatText = ReadBinary.Read(file, _object); //Right now this actually returns the text of an XML, but that doesn't matter much at the moment.
            } catch (IOException e) {
                DatText = "Unexpected error while reading .DAT file!";
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return DatText;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just strip off the extra bytes that ObjectInputStream should not see first with a FileInputStream.

```
static class MyObject implements Serializable{
    int i;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    obj.i = 77;
    File testFile = new File("test.dat");
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(testFile)) {
        fos.write(new byte[]{(byte) 0xFA, (byte) 0xCE, (byte) 0xAF, (byte) 0x0E});
        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)) {
            oos.writeObject(obj);
        }
    }
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(testFile)) {
        byte b4[] = new byte[4];
        fis.read(b4);
        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {
           MyObject newObj = (MyObject) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("newObj.i = " + newObj.i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would just make sure you are writing the data out the way I was. With an object output stream after the header required by the dat file. Whatever you do the write needs to match the read. Post the write code if you want me to match it.

Comment: OK. I've managed to get it working. The library of code that handles most of the stuff had a document for handing the .DAT (With the same code that exports it from the code as a .DAT), so I was able to modify my code accordingly. Other than that, your answer did work. Thanks!